# Implementing match-making with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, real-time

I'm using Ruby on Rails to build a real-time game web app. When a player taps "Play Now", I want to match them up with another player that is looking for a game (match-making). With my basic understanding of RoR, one immediate way I think I can do this is create a DB table that contains the players that are looking for a game. When a new player wants to play, I can just query the DB for the two most recent players and connect them together, and remove them from the DB. But this doesn't sound optimal since the list of players can potentially be large and the query could be slow.

Are there more efficient ways to implement this kind of match-making in RoR? Or a more efficient way to implement a persistent queue?

Other ideas?

Comment: Props to taking on the challenge of a real-time game +1

Answer (score 4):

Better idea - **use [Redis](http://redis.io)**

Redis is just like RAM for your app - the ability to store simple JSON notation objects which you can then call directly from your Rails app.

You'll be better storing people's player `ID`'s & other "match making" information in the Redis queue, with some sort of "worker" to process the queue - "matching" people to games.

---

**Redis**

You can read up an [excellent tutorial on Redis here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) (yes, I know it's about Resque):

[image]

---

**Queue**

Here's what I'd do:

> 1. Player clicks "Play Now"
> 2. Their ID & other data is appended to Redis
> 3. Once in the queue, a "worker" of sorts will clear out the Redis queue in blocks
> 4. Once player has been assigned a game, remove them from queue

A good demonstration of how this works (although I'm sure it's the same for other games) is World of Tanks "loading" screen ([good video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fySjvq9mgxI&list=UURJSv6FeQwTFnFDUroqp29A#t=1076) -- 17:57). This just puts players into a "queue", which the server then uses to allocate them into a battle.

In regards to the "processing" of the queue, you need to look at any scripts which could ensure the system will be able to process the players. I don't know whether [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) will be a good solution for this (it's not persistent & treats the Redis list as a "queue" of individual items)

---

**ROR**

Something you also need to consider is the role of ROR in this

I've been mulling over the idea of a "real time" game in RoR for some time, and have come to the conclusion that although Rails will be GREAT at rendering the HTML & backend functionality, in order to achieve a "real time" effect, you'll need another [layer of abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer)

This level of abstraction will be in the Javascript.

I mean that to achieve the "real time" nature of the app, you'll definitely want to use Ajax for sending requests *to* the server, and likely a `websocket` system to handle incoming messages *from* the server

The "magic" of the app will lie in how well you manage the integration between the Rails infrastructure & the front-end Ajax work. If you do it right, it *should* work really well indeed.

I guess what I want to stipulate is that **ROR is mainly for the backend** -- don't confuse yourself with thinking it can handle everything from the UI to the "real time" interactivity. In its current state, it can't

Comment: I can give you specifics on the code / infrastructure if you want

Comment: Thanks, Rich, excellent info. I should've mentioned the plan was to use websockets to manage the real-time interactivity and use RoR to serve up the pages. Fortunately, the game doesn't require rapid updates like an MMORPG or a FPS, in fact I could probably use polling, but that seems unnecessarily inefficient since we can use things like websockets now. Anyhow, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a table for all players who want to play now, how about having a table just for players that couldn't get an immediate match? Assume the model is PendingPlayer and the DB table pending_players, you could:

1. Player A presses "Play now". The system checks to see if PendingPlayer.count is greater than 0. Since Player A is the very first player, the check returns false.
2. When the check returns false, the player submitting the request gets placed in the pending_players table.
3. Another player - Player B - presses "Play now". Again the system checks if PendingPlayer.count is greater than 0, but this time it returns true.
4. When the check returns true, the player submitting the request is matched with the oldest record in pending_players, the appropriate record in pending_players is deleted, and a game is started.

This strategy should ensure that the pending_players table never grows very big, because it only writes a new record to the database when there is no one available to play. The same table could be used to catch "orphan" players whose playmates have suddenly left the game.